# Python extract substring with location of field and symbols

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I have been trying to clean a field in a csv file. The field is populated with numbers and characters, which I read into a panda dataframe and convert to a string.

Goal is to extract following variables: **StopId, StopCode** (possible to have multiple for each record), **rte**, **routeId** from the long string. Here is what I attempted so far.

After extracting the variables listed above, I need to merge the variable/codes with another file with location data per each stop/route/rte.

Sample records for the FIELD:

- 'Web Log: Page generated Query [cid=SM&rte=50183&dir=S&day=5761&dayid=5761&fst=0%2c&tst=0%2c]'
- 'Web Log: Page generated Query: [_=1407744540393&agencyId=SM&stopCode=361096&rte=7878%7eBus%7e251&dir=W]'
- Web Log: Page generated Query: [_=1407744956001&agencyId=AC&stopCode=55451&stopCode=55452stopCode=55489&&rte=43783%7eBus%7e88&dir=S]

Solutions I tried below, but I am stuck! Advice and recommendations are appreciated

```
    # Idea 1: Splits field above in a loop by '&' into a list. This is useful but I'll   
    # have to write additional code to pull out relevant variables
    i = 0
    for t in data['EVENT_DESCRIPTION']:
        s = list(t.split('&'))
        data['STOPS'][i] = [ x for x in s if "Web Log" not in x ]
        i+=1
    # Idea 1 next step help - how to pull out necessary variables from the list in data['STOPS']

    # Idea2: Loop through field with string to find the start and end of variable names. The output for stopcode_pl (et. al. variables) is tuple or list of tuples (if there are more than one in the string)

    for i in data['EVENT_DESCRIPTION']:
        stopcode_pl = [(a.start(), a.end() ) for a in list(re.finditer('stopCode=', i))]
        stopid_pl = i[(a.start(), a.end() ) for a in list(re.finditer('stopId=', i))]
        rte_pl = [(a.start(), a.end() ) for a in list(re.finditer('rte=', i))]
        routeid_pl = [(a.start(), a.end() ) for a in list(re.finditer('routeId=', i))]
    #Idea2: Next Step Help - how to use the string location for variable names to pull the number of the relevant variable. Is there a trick to grab the characters in between the variable name last place (i.e. after the '=' of the variable name) and the next '&'?
```

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
def qdata(rec):
    return [tuple(item.split('=')) for item in rec[rec.find('[')+1:rec.find(']')].split('&')]
```

yields, for instance, on the first record:

```
[('cid', 'SM'), ('rte', '50183'), ('dir', 'S'), ('day', '5761'), ('dayid', '5761'), ('fst', '0%2c'), ('tst', '0%2c')]
```

You can then step across that list searching for your specific items.